# AutoCAD C#/.Net: expose entities coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

My goal is to run my custom dll through AcCoreConsole and make various analysis on DWGs, such as expose Layer names and XY-coordinates on objects. I have managed to get all object in a selection set, and I can loop through the entities. When googling around a lot on this subject, I can't find any examples on how to extract coordinates from entities. I do understand that "coordinates" means different things whether it's a Circle or a Polyline for example.

Answer (score 2):

After some more hours of googling, I found the answer. Simple use GeometricExtents to get a boundingbox fo each entity, then calculate the midpoint with some simple math.

```
try
                        {
                            var entExtent = ent.GeometricExtents;
                            var midpointX = (entExtent.MaxPoint.X+entExtent.MinPoint.X)/2;
                            var midpointY = (entExtent.MaxPoint.Y+entExtent.MinPoint.Y)/2;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //edt.WriteMessage("\nGeometricExtents didn´t work on this entity");                                
                        }
```